# multibib with French and English parts

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing a document comprising French and English sections, for which I create independent bibliographies by using the package multibib. My problem is: Within the French part, the citation appears with "and" instead of "et" between the name of the authors, **although** the French bibliography list is correct (with the "et"). The English part works fine.

How can I force the use of "et" instead of "and" for the citations in the French part?

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{latex}{Références bibliographiques}
\begin{document}

Partie française : \citet{Xe2012}

English section: \citetlatex{Xe2012}

\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{bibliography}

\bibliographystylelatex{apalike-fr} 
\bibliographylatex{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

and the bibliography.bib file content

```
@article{Xe2012,
author = {Xe, Wa and Ma, Gi},
journal = {AAA},
number = {2},
pages = {139--142},
title = {{Title}},
volume = {40},
year = {2012}
}
```